# Slicing Pandas series

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, slice

I have the following code:

```
total_csv = pd.read_csv('total.csv',header=0).iloc[:,:]
column28=total_csv ['28']
column27=total_csv ['27']
column26=total_csv ['26']
column25=total_csv ['25']
column24=total_csv ['24']
column23=total_csv ['23']

master_values=(column23,column24,column25,column26,column27,column28)

In [68]:master_values
Out[68]: 
(0    6867.488928
 Name: 23, dtype: float64, 0    6960.779317
 Name: 24, dtype: float64, 0    7007.540137
 Name: 25, dtype: float64, 0    7031.11444
 Name: 26, dtype: float64, 0    7127.469389
 Name: 27, dtype: float64, 0    7408.207806
 Name: 28, dtype: float64)
```

But I want `master_values` to be `(6867.488928,6960.779317,7007.540137,7031.11444,7127.469389,7408.207806)`.

Currently, the way I read `total_csv` is the following:

```
In [69]: total_csv
Out[69]: 
     z           23           24          25  ...     
0  CCS  6867.488928  6960.779317  7031.11444  ...
```

How could I read `master_values` to be `(6867.488928,6960.779317,7007.540137,7031.11444,7127.469389,7408.207806)`?

Comment: `df.loc[0, ['28', '27, '26', '25, '24, '24]].tolist()`

Answer (score 0):

Are the columnXX variables necessary ?

Maybe just try following:
master_values = pd.read_csv('total.csv',header=0).iloc[0]

and if you need a tuple as indicated by the parentheses you can do it like that:
master_values = tuple(pd.read_csv('total.csv',header=0).iloc[0])

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
total_csv.to_numpy()[0][0].split('  ')[1:]
```